# PHP JSON match the specification

Tags: php, arrays, json, where-clause, decode

I've got a short question.

I have the following JSON array:

```
[{"id":"3fdb3ff4-7e57-ebf3628ead59","alias":"myalias1"},{"id":"f5e2fbd0-8dca-88b0555ab8d3","alias":"secondalias"}]
```

Now I want to save the id in a php variable, but "alias" have to match "myalias1".

E.g. `if ( $alias == "myalias1" ) { echo $idofmyalias1; }`

I hope you could help me.

Regards :)

Comment: Use `array_column()` to make an alias→id map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would decode the JSON literal using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then get the property value of an item in the decoded array.

Here is a quick example:

```
$literal = '[{"id":"3fdb3ff4-7e57-ebf3628ead59","alias":"myalias1"},{"id":"f5e2fbd0-8dca-88b0555ab8d3","alias":"secondalias"}]';
$parsed_literal = json_decode($literal);

if ($parsed_literal[0]->alias === 'myalias1') {
    echo $parsed_literal[0]->alias;
}
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/1BIWk)

Comment: I changed your if clause to:

foreach ($parsed_literal as $i => $value) { 
 if ( $value->alias === "myalias" ) { echo $value->id; } 
 }

With this every alias will be checked and not only the [0] one. :)